# Magento 2, add color style in Status column in sale order

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, order-grid

Using `Magento 2.2`, `Admin Grid`. I want to add style to **Status** column in sale order. *How to do this?*

[image]

Comment: <column name="status" class="Iota\EShopping\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>

Comment: I using class. @LAW

Comment: Yes my bad, I was thinking you wanted to make every block different color based on status. Sorry, my bad!

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a module named Vendor_Module. Create all the files and structure like below:

**Step 1:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/grid.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**Step 4:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**Step 5:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/grid.css

```
td.complete div {
    border: 1px solid #008000;
    padding: 5px 0px 6px 10px;
}

td.closed div{
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    padding: 5px 0px 6px 10px;
}

td.processing div{
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    padding: 5px 0px 6px 10px;
}

td.pending div{
    border: 1px solid #FFA500;
    padding: 5px 0px 6px 10px;
}
```

**Step 6:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/listing.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/listing'
], function (Collection) {
    'use strict';

    return Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/ui/grid/listing'
        },
        getRowClass: function (col,row) {
            if(col.index == 'status'){
                if(row.status == 'complete') {
                    return 'complete';
                } else if(row.status == 'closed') {
                    return 'closed';
                } else if(row.status == 'processing') {
                    return 'processing';
                } else {
                    return 'pending';
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Step 7:**

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/ui/grid/listing.html

```
<div class="admin__data-grid-wrap" data-role="grid-wrapper">
    <table class="data-grid" data-role="grid">
       <thead>
            <tr each="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'" render="getHeader()"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'">
                <td outerfasteach="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'"
                    css="$parent.getRowClass($col,$row());" click="getFieldHandler($row())" template="getBody()"/>
            </tr>
            <tr ifnot="hasData()" class="data-grid-tr-no-data">
                <td attr="colspan: countVisible()" translate="'We couldn\'t find any records.'"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

You can adjust the css from grid.css according to your requriement. You will get all classes according to your status.

Comment: your `listing.html` file replaces the `$parent.getRowClass($col,$row())` css data binding,which removes the css classes `data-grid-checkbox-cell` and `data-grid-actions-cell from the grid.  Can you update your template, to bring those classes back?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the step to apply style to your status field admin grid.

Vendor\Module Name\view\adminhtml\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <css src="<Vendor>_<Module Name>::css/style.css"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

After that create css file in your web folder like :

Vendor\Module Name\view\adminhtml\web\css\style.css
add your style here for different statuses.

If you still query then let me know.

Comment: Do i need to have a renderer for use with style?

Comment: No need to renderer. and run command.