# How to add a different class names to a field called status in UI component grid used in front-end in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to add a span tag for a status field which contains different statuses like close,open,order.those status are coming from ui component grid used in front-end.

Comment: You can refer this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/239275/magento-2-add-color-style-in-status-column-in-sale-order, may be helpful to you.

Comment: Can I follow the same steps for ui component grid which is used in front end

Comment: I have not tried yet. Please try once, may be it works for you.

Comment: thank u Dhara Bhatti, i have followed the steps for quote grid and it's working fine.

Comment: That's great. I'm happy to help. :)